# Can MCMCglmm in R be used similarly to lmer?

Tags: r, mixed-model, predictive-models, markov-chain-montecarlo, lme4-nlme

I am trying to predict the dispersal distance of plants via plant traits. I also want to include the phylogenetical relationships between species into the model, and add two random factors (species and plot ID). The response variable is continuous and the explanatory variables are a mix of continuous and categorical. Specifically I want to find out what traits of plant species best predict the dispersal distance of species (i.e. building the most parsimoniuous model). The model based on the lmer function would be:

```
mod1 <- lmer(dist ~ trait1 + trait2 + trait3 + (1|species) + (1|plotID),
             data=mydata, REML=T)
```

The according MCMCglmm model would like this (?):

```
# specify the prior distribution
prior <- list(G=list(G1=list(V=1,nu=0.002),
                     G2=list(V=1,nu=0.002),
                     G3=list(V=1,nu=0.002)),
              R=list(V=1,nu=0.002))

# transforming the phylogenetic tree into usable form
Ainv <- inverseA(species.phylo.tree, nodes="TIPS")$Ainv

# specify the model
mod.mcmc <- MCMCglmm(dist ~ trait1 + trait2 + trait3, 
             random=~species+plotID,
             prior=prior,
             nitt = 150000, burnin = 12000, thin = 100,
             family="gaussian", 
             ginverse=list(species=Ainv), 
             data=mydata)
```

My questions are:

1) Can the MCMCglmm function be used like this or is this approach total nonsense?

2) Can interactions and polynomial terms be used in MCMCglmm?

3) If the MCMCglmm model is not applicable, are there any appropriate solutions for including phylogenetic relationships into a prediction model?

Comment: Don't have high enough reputation to make this a comment, but just wanted to clarify something said in the accepted answer: > This utilises stan, which adopts a Hamiltonian Monte Carlo method,
> rather than MCMC. Hamiltonian Monte Carlo is a particular variant of MCMC. It's different than what MCMCglmm uses but still MCMC.

Comment: OK, I understand now, the reason you are considering `MCMCglmm` is because it supports the `ginverse` argument and the `inverseA` function to add phylo-specific correlations to the model. I don't have expertise in this, but it appears from reading the documentation that you are correct. I prefer more general-purpose packages like `brms` (which may also be able to do what you want) and `rstanarm` (which doesn't appear to do what you want), but you need a particular feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MCMCglmm` and `lmer` are both functions that can be used for fitting linear mixed models. `MCMCglmm` takes a Bayesian approach where priors must be specified for fixed and random effects, enabling inference via Markov Chain Monte Carlo sampling, whereas `lmer` takes a likelihood approach within the frequentist paradigm.  To answer your questions:

1. Yes, you have specified an equivalent model in `MCMCglmm` to the one in `lmer`. That is, you have specified fixed effects for `trait1`, `trait2` and `trait3` and crossed or nested (depending on how your data are coded) random effects for `species` and `plotID`.
2. Yes, you can use interactions and polynomials in the usual way.
3. You can use any package for fitting linear mixed models that supports crossed or nested random effects. If you are specifically interested in Bayesian models, then another option is the new `rstanarm` package. This utilises `stan`, which adopts a Hamiltonian Monte Carlo method, rather than MCMC.

Comment: +1. In particular, the `rstanarm` function that works like `lmer`, except being Bayesian, is `stan_lmer`.

Comment: Marty Panama commented: Hamilton Monte Carlo is an MCMC method. It's different from the more common Gibbs Sampling or Metropolis Hastings Sampling, but it does fall under the MCMC heading.